# Facebook post link to feed fails with uninformative error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On using Android Facebook SDK, I'm able to successfully post a message to the me/feed (so I guess the problem isn't with the session status or the permissions) but posting a link (with it's additional parameters) fails with error:

`{Response:  responseCode: 500, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 500, errorCode: 100, errorType: FacebookApiException, errorMessage: Invalid parameter}, isFromCache:false}`

I use hardcoded parameters that are confirmed to work in a different app.

What could this error mean?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and i was looping between it and require upload file permission error while trying to fix it.
I was sharing 2 types of posts : status and photos through using the link

https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid={POST-ID}&id={PAGE-ID}
or 
https://www.facebook.com/{PAGE-ID}/posts/{POST-ID}

but recently i found out the facebook seems to have made some changes and this way stopped working for photos, the only way to get it to work was through using the graph api to get the post link that exists with the post object and use it for posting.

example for getting the link from a post:

```
    Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), mPageID+ "/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            GraphMultiResult list = response.getGraphObjectAs(GraphMultiResult.class);
            if (list != null) {
                GraphObjectList<GraphObject> graphOList = list.getData();
                for (int i = 0; i < graphOList.size(); i++) {

                    GraphObject graphObjectItem = graphOList.get(i);
                    if (graphObjectItem != null) {
                        Post p = new Post();
                        if (graphObjectItem.getProperty("link") != null)
                            p.setURL(graphObjectItem.getProperty("link").toString());

                        if (graphObjectItem.getProperty("id") != null) {
                            p.setPostID(graphObjectItem.getProperty("id").toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    // i use execute and wait because i'm calling the function inside a background task
    Request.executeAndWait(request);
```

function that i used to share the link :

```
        public static void sharePost(String message, String link){  
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("message", message);
    b.putString("link", link);
    b.putString("access_token", Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken());

    Request postRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
            "/me/feed", b, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    responseMessage = response.toString();
                }
            });
    Request.executeAndWait(postRequest);
}
```

Comment: If this is meant to be an answer, it needs to be more specific. If it's a "me too" comment, please turn it into a comment. If it's a new question, ask a new question.